# Are christmas pajamas haram

Tags: halal-haram, clothing, celebration

I was wondering if christmas pajamas are haram because I just bought one and it says merry Christmas wich I know it's haram to say but also when I searched it up I saw many Muslims say you can have a tree as long as its not on Christmas or you can have red and green decor if it's not on Christmas I'm still young and don't want to commit shirk by accident so can someone please answer the question.